# OpenOCD debugging multiple devices at once

Tags: eclipse, debugging, openocd

I am trying to debug multiple devices at once with openocd on eclipse. I have 2x STM32F303 discovery borards, I have set the hla_serial flag to a proper board, but still no luck.

Separate boards are doing ok, but when trying to debug it's Eclipse saying it'came to error in last sequence.

So if anyone had experience with that. Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We can use hla_serial option within openocd 0.9+ *ONLY*. I'd recommend to download from 
[GNU ARM Eclipse](http://gnuarmeclipse.livius.net/blog/2015/03/20/gnu-arm-eclipse-openocd-0-9-0-20150320-dev-released/) project or compile yourself.

To obtain hla_serial, the easiest way found after reading the patch that included this option (http://openocd.zylin.com/#/c/2198/), more specific  function "[string_descriptor_equal](http://openocd.zylin.com/#/c/2198/8/src/jtag/drivers/libusb0_common.c)", was to provide a wrong serial, so it would print the correct one.

The command below will create file **log_with_correct_serial.txt**. Switch board config file for the one currently being used.

```
openocd.exe -d3 -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg  -c "hla_serial wrong_serial" 2>log_with_correct_serial.txt
```

Opening **log_with_correct_serial.txt** you will find correct serial in line containing something like

```
 Debug: 229 23 libusb1_common.c:67 string_descriptor_equal(): Device serial number 'xxxxxxxxxxx' doesn't match requested serial 'wrong_serial'
```

So create a derived config (for example **stm32f4discovery-mydevice1.cfg**, assuming stm32f4discovery is used) inside folder **board** on openocd root directory. Use something like Notepad++ to copy serial as it is hex numbers.

```
# This is an STM32F4 discovery board with a single STM32F407VGT6 chip.
# http://www.st.com/internet/evalboard/product/252419.jsp
# hla_serial thanks to http://wunderkis.de/stlink-serialno/index.html

source [find board/stm32f4discovery.cfg]
hla_serial V?nIpSU)?
```

Now to open your device you can use the command below to start debugging using ST-Link adapter.

```
openocd.exe -f board/stm32f4discovery-mydevice1.cfg
```

In each eclipse project provides a different board config for each project and you are good to go.