# OpenOCD multiple STLinks

Tags: stm32, openocd

I need to be connect to 2 STM32s over 2 ST-Links at the same time. I found this issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121050/openocd-debugging-multiple-devices-at-once).

However, solution doesn't work for me.

ST-Link ID1: 55FF6B067087534923182367
ST-Link ID2: 49FF6C064983574951291787

OpenOCD cfg file:

```
source [find interface/stlink-v2.cfg]
hla_serial "55FF6B067087534923182367"

source [find target/stm32f4x.cfg]

# use hardware reset, connect under reset
reset_config srst_only srst_nogate
```

I get:

```
$ openocd.exe -f stm32f4_fmboard.cfg
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
adapter speed: 2000 kHz
adapter_nsrst_delay: 100
none separate
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain connect_deassert_srst
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 2000 kHz, using 1800 kHz
Info : clock speed 1800 kHz
Error: open failed
in procedure 'init'
in procedure 'ocd_bouncer'
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if solved but:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/prog/bootloader $ st-info --probe
Found 1 stlink programmers
serial: 363f65064b46323613500643
openocd: "\x36\x3f\x65\x06\x4b\x46\x32\x36\x13\x50\x06\x43"
flash: 0 (pagesize: 0)
sram: 0
chipid: 0x0000
descr: unknown device
```

this tool shows serial of st-links and there is option called openocd. When I put `hla_serial "\x36\x3f\x65\x06\x4b\x46\x32\x36\x13\x50\x06\x43"` in file then it works for me. Your way does not. It also does not work in command line given as argument. It works only as I described in `cfg` file

Answer (score 0):

The format of the configuration file seems to have changed recently. The following applies for `Open On-Chip Debugger 0.10.0+dev-00634-gdb070eb8 (2018-12-30-23:05)`.

Find out the serial number with `lsusb`, `st-link`, or with `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id`. The latter yields (with two  STLink/V2.1 connected):

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Nov 30 14:31 usb-STMicroelectronics_STM32_STLink_066CFF323535474B43125623-if02 -> ../../ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Dec 30 23:55 usb-STMicroelectronics_STM32_STLink_0672FF485457725187052924-if02 -> ../../ttyACM1
```

The specification on the `.cfg`-file is now **plain hex**. Do **not** use the C string syntax any longer. For selecting the latter device, simply write:

```
#hla_serial "066CFF323535474B43125623"
hla_serial "0672FF485457725187052924"
```